# Set width for flextable in a Word document with officer

Tags: r, flextable, officer

I have a very simple task.  Create a flextable (or qflextable) from a data frame.  And then print it in Word.  It is a 4 column table.  The first column is a descriptive label and the other 3 are percentages or counts.  In the first row below the header, first column, the cell contents are long but not excessive (about 10 words, so it should wrap 2-3 times).

When I print as qflextable (which is just flextable with auto fit, from what I gather), I get a table that doesn't fit on the page because it fits that first row without wrapping.  When I used flextable, no matter what I do, it is a narrow table (each column is about 1") that fits and wraps the long text, but I can't seem to adjust its width from R.

Either way, if I open the Word document, and set the table properties to 6.5 inches, which is what I would like to do, the table looks great.

I can't tell if this is a flextable or officer issue.  And I can't seem to figure out how to use table_width() or prop_table(table_width(6.5, "in")) in conjunction with a table.  The help file doesn't have a parameter for a table -- the function inputs are simply width and unit.

My code is below:

```
at <- flextable(at)

tabdoc <- read_docx(path = "path here"))
tabdoc <- 
    body_add_par(tabdoc, value = sectcap, style = "heading 1") %>% 
    body_add_caption(table1cap) %>% 
    body_add_flextable(at)
```

Any help with the syntax for setting the table width, or even setting individual column widths, would be appreciated.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57175351/4241780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reproducible example would be useful.

What worked for me was to specifically set the width of the first column:

```r
at <- width(qflextable(at), j=1, width=4)
```

Comment: That works.  I was trying to set the table properties, but I can manually set the first column.  Thank you.